# Filter tokens in a list based on frequency

Tags: python, filter, counter, frequency

I am working on a list object containing several tokens with different frequency

```
from collections import Counter

s = {'book',
 'car',
 'bird',
 'cup',
 'book',
 'cup',
 'river'}

print(Counter(s))

[('book': 2), ('cup': 2), ('river': 1), ('car': 1), ('bird': 1)]
```

I want to set a filter by which only tokens that have appeared twice will be selected, and my use the following code in my current attempt

```
select = [word for word in s if list(s).count(word) >= 2]
select
```

I thought it's very straightforward, but I didn't any output from 'select.' What went wrong with my code and how to deal with it?

Comment: You show a *set*, which will only have each unique value *once*. Please give a [mcve]; note that stack snippets are for HTML/CSS/JS and do not support Python.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In case `s` is a **list** and not a set (like you wrote in your question, but not in the code in your example), you can use the `most_common` function of the `Counter` object to get the top X elements in your list:

```
In [67]: s = ['book',
    ...:  'car',
    ...:  'bird',
    ...:  'cup',
    ...:  'book',
    ...:  'cup',
    ...:  'river']

In [68]: s
Out[68]: ['book', 'car', 'bird', 'cup', 'book', 'cup', 'river']

In [69]: c = Counter(s)

In [70]: c.most_common(2)
Out[70]: [('book', 2), ('cup', 2)]
```

In case you want to get elements that appear more than Y times you can use:

```
In [71]: [x[0] for x in c.items() if x[1] >= 2]
Out[71]: ['book', 'cup']
```

`x[0]` is the item (from the list) and `x[1]` is the frequency

Comment: This is not why I want, '.most_common()' only ranks them.

Comment: Could you explain the difference between x[0] and x[1]?

Comment: Ok, I got it. Thanks.